# Can the id of a mysql table start with 0?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an array that gives me the order of different of different concepts I have in a table. As it is an array it begins with 0. I have different options to store the order of the concepts. My questions are:

1. Is this correct to make the id of a MySql table begin with 0?. If so, it would be the easiest option
2. If not, can I make the array begin with 1?
3. A third option would be to create a column just to store the order. This creates a new problem  when the user creates a new item. As MySql does not accept 2 auto-increment columns.

```php
$order = $_GET['order'];
print_r ($order); // this gives: Array ( [0] => first [1] => second [2] => third )

foreach($order as $key => $value) {
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE principal 
                       SET concept = $value
                       WHERE id = $key");
}
```

Comment: The ID itself can be anything that's unique. Even a UUID string. If your question is specific to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, well, you don't want/need that if you want to assign IDs manually.

Comment: The id is auto-increment and must be asigned automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you apparently want to use the same column for two entirely different purposes:

- Uniquely identify the row
- Store its display order

While it can probably be done, IMHO it's confusing and hard to maintain. From the design point of view it's better to simply use two columns. It's cleaner and it doesn't force you to update keys in all the linked tables whenever you need to set a different order.

As about the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature, it's a mechanism designed to generate unique incrementing *meaningless* numbers. It's primary designed for [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) and it doesn't allow something as simple as reusing values.

Your other questions:

> Is this correct to make the id of a MySql table begin with 0?

There's nothing wrong with that (I actually do it now and then) but MySQL has a feature that makes it hard to do: [NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero)

> If not, can I make the array begin with 1?

If you type the array:

```
$foo = array(1 => 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

If you already have it:

```
foreach($order as $key => $value) {
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE principal 
        SET concept = $value
        WHERE id = " . ($key+1));
}

$key = 0;
foreach($order as $value) {
    $key++;
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE principal 
        SET concept = $value
        WHERE id = $key");
}

foreach(array_values($order) as $key => $value) {
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE principal 
        SET concept = $value
        WHERE id = " . ($key+1));
}

// ...
```

Comment: The answer to my question 2. I think I cannot apply to this case as it is a dynamic table and I do not know the values

Comment: I've added two more suggestions

Answer (score 1):

*Is this correct to make the id of a MySql table begin with 0?* - **NO**

*If not, can I make the array begin with 1?* - **YES**

*As MySql does not accept 2 auto-increment columns.* - You should change your DB design so that you can co relate primary / foreign data.

Now am not aware of what your exact requirements are, but you should split the data in two different tables, with a common column in both the tables which will act as primary/foreign keys between the two.

---

If you want to start an array id from 1 than use

```
<?php
    $arr = array("a","b","c");
    array_unshift($arr,"");
    unset($arr[0]);
    print_r($arr);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/F2LE3X)

Comment: how can I make the key of this array begin with 1?